# How to close something when you click on something else?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a fun website for my friends and family, and one aspect of it is to click on a button, and their bio shows up. What I want is where you click on a different bio, and the previous one disappears. How can I do this?
jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.page-body2').hide();
  $('.page-body3').hide();
  $('.family-photo1').on('click', function(){
    $('.page-body2').toggle();
  });
  $('.family-photo2').on('click', function(){
    $('.page-body3').toggle();
  });
  ***CODE HERE?***
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="page-body2">
      <div class="bren"><b>Brendon:</b></div>
      <p>**BIO**</p>
    </div><div class="page-body3">
      <div class="heath"><b>Heather:</b></div>
      <p>**BIO**</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try giving all the bios the same class name.   This is what you will close on then give each one a different id name, this is the one you open.   Basically on a click you will $(".bios").hide() and then $("#Bio1").show().

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BBaughn/fvd9wt4m/

Answer (score 1):

I prepared a demo for you: https://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/dordnd9r/1/

```
$('.hideBio').hide();
$('button').click(function(){    
    $('.hideBio').fadeOut(200);//hide all bio each time
    $(this).prev('p').fadeIn(200);//show only the selected one
});
```

Comment: @BrendonBaughn could you please mark my answer as the correct one if it helped?

Answer (score 0):

For a better UX

```
$('.hideBio').hide();
$('button').click(function(){   
    var l=$(this);
    $('.hideBio').fadeOut(100,function(){
            l.prev('p').fadeIn(100);
    }); 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6tr0ey9r/1/